# Is there a way to check and see if two objects have properties in common?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

So if I have a JSON file with n number of objects in it, each of them having n number of properties, and two of the objects having one property in common, is there a way to, in an external JavaScript file, check to see which two objects in the JSON file have a property in common.  To take it a step further, is there a way to then see if there are more properties in common between these two?  I did research and found nothing on this exact topic, only a post about checking to see if a given object has a given property in it.

Thanks a lot if you can help!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code you've been working on?

Comment: @Geuis I haven't tried anything because I have no clue as to where I should start.  I have my code here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/petal-canid?path=app.js:160:64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `object.keys()` and filter the array based on the common properties. Please check browser compatibility of `Object.keys()` before using.

```js
var obj1 = {
name:'hello',
age:12,
fav: 'fav',
foo: 'foo'
}

var obj2 = {
name: 'hey',
say: 'say',
prop: 'prop',
top: 'top'
}

var common = Object.keys(obj1).filter(obj1item =>  Object.keys(obj2).indexOf(obj1item) !== -1 );

console.log(common);
```

`Object.keys()` returns an array of properties. We are comparing both the arrays for common properties.

Object.keys():  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Array.filter(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter