# How to compare if second object has some value in first object then return true?

Tags: javascript

I want to compare two objects as below:

First object:

```
const permissions = {
  "statistics":{"list":"1"},"audit":{"list":"1"}}
}
```

Second object:

```
const userPermission = 
{
  "audit":{"list":"1"}
}
```

So, if the second object has some value the same as the first object then return true.
In this sample I want it return `true`.  Becuase, `audit` has same properties.

Comment: And you have an extra `}`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, I don't want to compare all objects. Just want to check if it has in other property even it has only one which matches property then return it true.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj1 = {
name:'hello',
age:12,
fav: 'fav',
foo: 'foo'
}

var obj2 = {
name: 'hey',
say: 'say',
prop: 'prop',
top: 'top'
}

var common = Object.keys(obj1).filter(obj1item =>  Object.keys(obj2).indexOf(obj1item) !== -1 );

console.log(common);
```

You can look into this > [Is there a way to check and see if two objects have properties in common?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461105/is-there-a-way-to-check-and-see-if-two-objects-have-properties-in-common/51461201)